# $S=\{(x, 1, 1, 1),(1, x, 1, 1),(1, 1, x, 1),(1, 1, 1, x)\}$, find out $\text{span}(S)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For which real numbers $x$, the set $S=\{(x, 1, 1, 1),(1, x, 1, 1),(1, 1, x, 1),(1, 1, 1, x)\}$
will not form a basis for $\mathbb R^4$ and in this case, find out $\text{span}(S)$?

As we know that for $x\ne 1$ it will form basis because if $x=1$, all four vectors will become linearly dependent and so, will not form a basis. By seeing, I think they will span $\mathbb R^4$ but I'm not sure how to prove it. Can anyone tell how to prove it?

Comment: You should be able to compute the determinant and explicitly compute the inverse matrix. Try transforming it into an upper triangular matrix first. In particular, there's one other value of $x$ for which the matrix is singular and thus doesn't form a basis.